# Adding Parameter to DateDiff Function

Tags: ms-access

Not sure I am going at this the best way, I would like to make the last parameter of the DateDiff formula something the user enters.  I get the parameter popup, but when I enter the desired date in the popup I get an error (screen shot of error is below):

Interest Days: DateDiff("d",Nz([Loan]![SetupDate],DateAdd("m",-1,[Loan]![CreationDate])),Format([Enter the date you wish to pull from],"mm/dd/yyyy")+1)

I have tried putting a # in the parameter popup and I also tried not putting the parameter in a Format, like this but it results in the same error:

Interest Days: DateDiff("d",Nz([Loan]![SetupDate],DateAdd("m",-1,[Loan]![CreationDate])),[Enter the date you wish to pull from]+1)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNrJi.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, specify the Parameter as *DateTime*:

```
[Enter the date you wish to pull from]
```

Next, use it as a *date*:

```
Interest Days: DateDiff("d",Nz([Loan]![SetupDate],DateAdd("m",-1,[Loan]![CreationDate])),[Enter the date you wish to pull from])+1
```

Comment: Thanks.  When you say "Use it as a date" do you mean to put the parameter in a Format function like my first example?

Comment: No, then it would no longer be a date.

Comment: I’m curious how asking the user to enter a DateTime format make this work?  If they enter 01/31/2022 12:00:00 it still errors out on my side.

Comment: Why would they enter the time?

Comment: Because you suggested I specify DateTime in the parameter.

Comment: It accepts date and time but doesn't require both.

Comment: I think I am doing everything correctly, I don't think Access can handle the calc for some reason.  When I use Date() instead of the Parameter it works great.  But when I put the parameter in there it gives me the error.

Comment: Can't tell. It works nicely here. So, double-check and/or reduce your query.

Comment: Figured it out, it doesn't like +1 at the end... when I take that out it works. Since it's always the EOM date required I will just change the parameter to say [First Day of Following Month] or something like that.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: This also worked: DateAdd("d",+1,[Enter EOM Date])

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered, if you feel so.